# What playlist format does Android 2.2 support to stream?

Tags: android, stream, audio-streaming, playlist

Hello i am trying to get my android 2.2 app stream music. So far I have been able to stream from a radio station via the `mediaPlayer.setDataSource("STREAM HERE")`

I have tried with a m3u file and it won't work (unless my m3u file is wrong). Can it support xspf or what other file types?

How could i go about solving this problem?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setDataSource()` method on the media player will accept file or URIs for a media source. Look at this list to see what media formats the media player accepts: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I am fairly certain that the media player will not play playlist files like M3U. You would have to create your own M3U player, which could be accomplished via the `MediaPlayer` method: `setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener)`

> Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media source has been reached during playback.

When playback is done, you could start playing the next media resource in your playlist.

Comment: so doing something like this: mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

Comment: Yes, something like that... and when you get the callbacks saying that the stream has ended, then you can load up the next song on your list.

If this solution is satisfactory, please accept this solution as the answer for your question.